# Additional colored row over text

Tags: basic, qbasic, quickbasic

I wanted to make a fake program in basic just to record it later and share with friends, but I have a problem, there is a colored row over a text, I want to make just background of text blue. Thanks for any help. [CLICK IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFscM.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, a typical DOS screen (which is what I'm assuming you're trying to emulate) is 25 lines in height, not 30, so you should try:

```
LOCATE 25,1
```

Second, if you don't trail your PRINT line with a semicolon (;) it will force a line-feed into another line.  You're not seeing the line because I believe that's what's causing your blue blank line - it's locating to line 30, printing the text, then no semicolon, so it scrolls another line which moves your colored blank line up.

Try the PRINT line with a semicolon at the end.

Comment: yeah, i added semicolon and now everything works, thanks Bill! :D